# Paramiko PKey.from_private_key_file gives me "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filename'"

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I get very weird behaviour from paramiko:

```
bla=paramiko.pkey.PKey(msg=None,data=None).from_private_key_file()
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-13288f655ecf> in <module>
----> 1 paramiko.pkey.PKey(msg=None,data=None).from_private_key_file()

TypeError: from_private_key_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'
```

here it tells me I need a filename, but then whenever I try to specify anything:

```
bla=paramiko.pkey.PKey(msg=None,data=None).from_private_key_file('key')
```

```
                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-5fa0cf9b6317> in <module>
----> 1 bla=paramiko.pkey.PKey(msg=None,data=None).from_private_key_file('key')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py in from_private_key_file(cls, filename, password)
    233         :raises: `.SSHException` -- if the key file is invalid
    234         """
--> 235         key = cls(filename=filename, password=password)
    236         return key
    237 

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filename'
```

Can anyone explain to me what's happening? I'm completely confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [`PKey.from_private_key_file`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/keys.html#paramiko.pkey.PKey.from_private_key_file) is a class method.
2. Do not use [`PKey` base class](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/keys.html#paramiko.pkey.PKey) directly. You have to use the correct descendant class, like [`RSAKey`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/keys.html#paramiko.rsakey.RSAKey), [`DSSKey`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/keys.html#paramiko.dsskey.DSSKey), etc.

As the [documentation](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/keys.html#paramiko.pkey.PKey.from_private_key_file) says:

> Through the magic of Python, this factory method will exist in all subclasses of PKey (such as [RSAKey](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/keys.html#paramiko.rsakey.RSAKey) or [DSSKey](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/keys.html#paramiko.dsskey.DSSKey)), but is useless on the abstract PKey class.

The correct code is like:

```
key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('key')
```

---

Though if you are going to use the key with [`SSHClient`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html), you can pass the filename directly to `key_filename` argument of [`SSHClient.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect) and you do not have to deal with key loading at all.